# What happens to legacy cookies that were set before once Same Site, Secure Changes are rolled out by Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies, samesite

Since with Chrome 80(upcoming change in Feb2020), they are enforcing SameSite and Secure attributes to be set in a cookie to access that on a third party context. What happens to the existing cookies that are already in the browser which does not have SameSite and Secure attribute. Once Chrome rolls out its changes, will those legacy cookies sent on third party context?

Answer (score 1):

Existing cookies without a `SameSite` attribute will be treated as if they are `SameSite=Lax`and restricted to a first party context. If you have existing cookies that need do not currently have the attribute and will need to be sent in a third-party context you should be actively refreshing them now.